# Step back a couple of revisions in git branch

Tags: git

I'm still new to git, so bear with me. I started adding a feature to my project in my current branch and committed it, then found out that I needed to add a more important feature first. (If I had thought about it, I would have just put the new feature into another branch but alas - hindsight is 20/20.)

I want to go back to my previous commit, add the more important feature and then add the less important feature that I already committed. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you commited to your local branch but havent pushed to the remote branch?

Comment: yeah, I've only committed the new feature to my local branch

Comment: Fine. So, any of the answers below will solve it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That mean rewriting the commit history of your branch, which is possible (practical) only if you do not have already pushed said branch to another repo.

If you do not pushed that branch, you have:

```
o---x---x---F1a---F1b---F1c <-- current branch
```

Mark it as branch F1

```
$ git branch F1

o---x---x---F1a---F1b---F1c <-- current branch, F1
```

Reset your current branch to before F1

```
$ git reset x

o---x---x---F1a---F1b---F1c <-- F1
        ^
        |
       current branch
```

Make your Feature 0 F0 (the one that should have been done before F1)

```
$ git commit ...

o---x---x---F0a---F0b <-- current branch
        ^
        |
        ---F1a---F1b---F1c <-- F1
```

Rebase F1 branch on top of current branch

```
$ git checkout F1
$ git rebase current
$ git checkout current
$ git merge F1 # fast-formward merge

o---x---x---F0a---F0b---F1a'---F1b'---F1c' <-- current branch, F1
```

---

If you did already pushed that feature, some revert is in order (see [Diego's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554045/step-back-a-couple-of-revisions-in-git-branch/2554125#2554125))

Comment: wow ... one day I hope to understand all that. Right now, I think it will work. Thanks for explaining it in detail.

Comment: @mozillalives: branches are just pointer in a graph of commits. You can reset that pointer to a previous commit and make new commits. As long as another branch (pointer) reference your old commits, their are still available (and not subject to be removed - pruned - from the repo). Those old commits can then be replayed on top of any branch (like the current one, with its new commit).

Comment: Re: "possible (practical) only if you do not have already pushed said branch to another repo" I know this is the common wisdom/guideline, but I don't find it universally true. Git is crazily flexible, so there are uses when forced pushes make sense.

Answer (score 8):

Probably the best way is to check out a new branch based on the point where you want to add the new feature.

```
git checkout -b newfeature <oldcommit>
```

Where `<oldcommit>` is either a commit id or a relative reference such as (e.g.) `HEAD~3` three commits before the current `HEAD`.

Once the feature is complete you can go back to your original branch and choose either to merge it in or to rebase the work on top of the `newfeature` branch. One of the great things about git is that you don't have to order all your work sequentially, indeed it often makes more sense to not force your history into one linear sequence of commits.

Comment: I was about to ask a new question, but this answered it to the letter, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just commited to your local branch, its an easy task

- go to another branch: `git checkout -b moreimportantfeature` . The new branch won't have the changes you commited. So you can add the new feature and push to the remote repo, or do a `git rebase otherbranch` to push both changes

If you have pushed to the repo:

- use `git revert HEAD` (or some variant HEAD^n if you want to get back on more commits). Then push your changes.